# How to make the script end with exit code 1 under a certain condition

Tags: node.js

I have a `runner.js` nodejs script that runs several nodejs processes in the loop. Its look like this (here part of code):

```
function run_process(i, attempts) {
    var n = i + 1;
    console.log(`[START] [${n}] > run ${n} of ${commands.length}`);
    console.log(`[START] [${n}] > ${commands[i]}`);

    running++;

    var args = commands[i].split(" ");
    var npm = spawn("npm", args, {
        cwd: undefined,
        env: process.env
    });

    var stdout = '';
    var stderr = '';


    npm.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        stdout += data;
    });

    npm.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        stderr += data;
    });

    npm
        .on('error', function (error) {
            console.error(`[ERROR] [${n}] > ${error}`);
        })
        .on('close', function (code, signal) {
            console.log(`[END] [${n}] > stdout: ${stdout}`);
            console.log(`[END] [${n}] > commandline: npm ${commands[i]}`);
            console.log(`[END] [${n}] > process exited with code ${code}`);

            if (code === 1) {
                allProcessSuccess = false;

                if (stderr.length > 0) {
                    console.log(`[STDERROR] [${n}] > stderr:\n ${stderr}`);
                }
            }

            if (signal) {
                console.log(`[SIGNAL] [${n}] > signal ${signal}`);
            }



            running--;
            run_processes();
        });
}

function run_processes() {

    while (running < MAX_INSTANCES && current < commands.length) {
        run_process(current, 0);
        current++;
    }
}

return run_processes();
```

Some of these processes may end with exit code 1. But the `runner.js` script itself ends with exit code 0.
I'm trying to add a condition that if at least one process terminates with exit code 1, then the `runner.js` script itself at the end of the work should also end with exit code 1.
For it I add variable `allProcessSuccess` and set it to `false` if any process terminated with exit code 1.
And also I try add this code:

```
if (allTestsSuccess === false) {
    return process.exit(1);
}
```

But if I add this code inside `run_processes` function like this:

```
function run_processes() {

    while (running < MAX_INSTANCES && current < commands.length) {
        run_process(current, 0);
        current++;
    }

    if (allTestsSuccess === false) {
        return process.exit(1);
    }
}
```

script exited with code 1 immediteary after first process which exit with code 1.

But if I put it in the end of script, like this:

```
run_processes();

if (allTestsSuccess === false) {
    return process.exit(1);
}
```

it never executed.

What I does wrong? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the main process is forced to exit after first call of `run_processes()`

```
function run_processes() {

    while (running < MAX_INSTANCES && current < commands.length) {
        run_process(current, 0); // this is async so
        current++;
    }

    // because above was async, the below will be executed
    if (allTestsSuccess === false) {
        return process.exit(1);
    }
}
```

The solution

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

let exitCode = 0;
let ended = true;
let queue = 0;

function evaluateAndExit() {
  if (ended && queue === 0) {
    process.exit(exitCode);
  }
}

function run_process(i) {
  if (i === MAX_INSTANCES || i === commands.length) {
    return ended = true;
  }
  queue++;
  ended = false;
  var args = commands[i].split(" ");
  var n = i + 1;
  var npm = spawn("npm", args);
  console.log(`[START] [${n}] > run ${n} of ${commands.length}`);
  console.log(`[START] [${n}] > ${commands[i]}`);
  var stdout = '';
  var stderr = '';
  npm.stdout.on('data', (data) => { stdout += data; });
  npm.stderr.on('data', (data) => { stderr += data; });
  npm
    .on('error', (error) => { console.error(`[ERROR] [${n}] > ${error}`); })
    .on('close', function (code, signal) {
      queue--;
      console.log(`[END] [${n}] > stdout: ${stdout}`);
      console.log(`[END] [${n}] > commandline: npm ${commands[i]}`);
      console.log(`[END] [${n}] > process exited with code ${code}`);
      if (code === 1) {
        exitCode = 1;
        if (stderr.length > 0) {
          console.log(`[STDERROR] [${n}] > stderr:\n ${stderr}`);
        }
      }
      if (signal) {
        console.log(`[SIGNAL] [${n}] > signal ${signal}`);
      }
      evaluateAndExit();
    });
  run_process(i+1);
}

run_process(0);
```

Comment: It does not works with this script... I get an error:
npm.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
               ^
TypeError: npm.stdout.on is not a function

Comment: try the new complete solution, that is async, recursive and simple. You were unnecessary trying to complex your code